# Is it possible to create a FIPS 140-2 compliant server in Perl?

Tags: perl, security, encryption, cryptography, fips

The question is pretty simple, is it possible to create a FIPS 140-2 compliant server in Perl? Especially, is it possible without modifying any of the C code for the modules? If it's not possible in straight Perl, what would be the easiest way to go about it from a C perspective?

I'm basically creating a mini-httpd that only serves up a single file, but due to security restrictions it needs to be served up on SSL under FIPS compliance.

Comment: A link to something describing what is "compliant" would be helpful, since I bet most readers are not familiar with this certification.

Comment: I am totally unware about it; searching found [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_140-2) as almost first, which is a starting point (not the best maybe, but to have an idea is ok...)

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what it is myself, Wikipedia about sums up my knowledge of the compliance as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know all of the rules when it comes to FIPS 140-2.  However,  unlike HIPAA and PCI-DSS its a standard that governs the strength of cryptography and doesn't take the system as a whole into consideration.   Parts of OpenSSL can be FIPS 140-2 compliant and this library is exposed to perl via the [Crypt::OpenSSL](http://perl-openssl.sourceforge.net/) module.   You just have to make sure your key size is large enough for the level of FIPS certification you need and that you don't violate a one of the many [Cryptographic Issues](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/310.html).

Comment: No! OpenSSL itself is ***not*** FIPS-approved, and never will be. The OpenSSL FIPS Object Module exists, and is FIPS-certified. See http://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/fipsnotes.html to open **that** can of worms.

Comment: Thank. I'm still not sure that the FIPS-compliant library is going to be exposed via Crypt::OpenSSL by default, though. You might have to check what it's linked against, and maybe go into the guts of the module to invoke startuppy stuff.

Comment: Thanks, I'll research more into this option.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Mozilla's [FIPS strategy](https://wiki.mozilla.org/FIPS_Validation). Triple DES is most likely to be Open Source. I am unaware of any certified FIPS 140-2 solutions in Perl.

Most implementation approvals are very restrictive, such as being on a certain hardware platform, CPU, and OS version. If you are on one of those platforms, you can often piggyback on the OS approval, such as Windows 7, Redhat, etc.